# get parameter error when try to sort google sheets by 2 columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried to do simple sort by 2 columns, there is many examples. but I got parameter error.
and cant understand why
here is my code:

```
function myFunction1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var dateColumn = 1;
  var houerColumn = 3;

  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.sort([{ column: 1, ascending: true }, { column: 3, ascending: true}]);
};
```

and the error I got is:
Exception: Cannot convert '[object Object],[object Object]' to int.
on row number 10 (the sort row).
what do I do wrong?

Comment: Can you give us an extract of your data, or look closely what values are in A10 and C10. Pls, precise also which sheet do you want to sort : you first choose the active sheet, then the first sheet (index 0) = may be the line `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]` is not necessary.

Comment: There are no object parameters in sheet sort: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#sort(Integer,Boolean)  There is just an integer and a boolean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are over-complicating things.  The way you're trying to sort is usually done on ranges, not sheets.
This code should suffice:

```
function myFunction1(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().sort([{ column: 1, ascending: true }, { column: 3, ascending: true}]);
}
```